# Structuring real time location data request from firebase using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location, data-retrieval

So I'm trying to retrieve the location of a "paired user" (i.e. not the current user but a contact of the current user) and monitor the distance travelled and distance relative to the currentUser. When using the code below I am only able to retrieve a list with multiple entries of the same location rather than consistently getting only the new location update of the 'paired user'.

```
func retrieveLocations() {
        let locationDB = Database.database().reference().child("Locations").child("nameOfUser")

locationDB.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded)
            { (snapshot) in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,Any>

        let lats = snapshotValue["Lat"]
        let longs = snapshotValue["Lon"]
        let timeOf = snapshotValue["Time"]
        let sender = snapshotValue["Sender"]


  let otherUsersLocations = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(truncating: lats! as! NSNumber), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(truncating: longs! as! NSNumber), timestamp: timeOf as! Int)
print("Latitude: \(otherUsersLocations.coordinate.latitude), Longitude: \(otherUsersLocations.coordinate.longitude), Time: \(timeOf), Sender: \(sender)")
```

I later call the function in the same func that I use to update the current users location. The code below is used to update the current users location to firebase.[Firebase Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFv82.jpg)

```
let locationDictionary = [

            "Sender": Auth.auth().currentUser?.email,
            "Lat": latitude,
            "Lon": longitude,
            "Speed": speed,
            "Time": ServerValue.timestamp()

            ] as [String : Any]


        locationDB.childByAutoId().setValue(locationDictionary) {
            (error, reference) in
            if error != nil {
                                print(error!)
                            }
                            else {

                            }
        }


    }

    retrieveLocations()
```

I have tried creating a new "LocationModel" object but had troubles feeding the dictionary of LocationModel type with the retrieved data from firebase.
So my objective is to retrieve an array/dictionary of the location data for the paired user from "now" and subsequently measure the distance to the currentUser.

I've been sitting at this for a while so I really appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks a lot!

Pat